# Angular Google Maps ui-gmap-markers labels

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I've created angular app with google maps. On the map I display markers. But it's still not obvious for me how to create a label which will be opened on click (on pin).

Help me please

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
    <ui-gmap-circle center='map.marker'
       radius='8046'
       fill='map.circle.fill'
       stroke='map.circle.stroke'>
   </ui-gmap-circle>
   <ui-gmap-markers models="notices"
       coords="'location'">
   </ui-gmap-markers>
   </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `<ui-gmap-windows>` tag inside `<ui-gmap-markers>` tag

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClick'">
    <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
        <div ng-non-bindable>{{title}}</div>
    </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```